# I can't get a member inside a private class to be accessible from another private class

Tags: c#, private, member

```
    {
    public partial class form1 : Form
    {
        public form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public Button ButtonName { get { return } }
        public static int initFaggleCount;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int faggleCount = initFaggleCount++;
            string finalCalc = faggleCount.ToString();
            label1.Text = finalCalc;
            /*
            Console.WriteLine(faggleCount);
            Console.ReadLine();*/
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("SavedFaggleCount.txt");
            tw.WriteLine();
            tw.Close();*/
            Console.WriteLine(faggleCount);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the integer faggleCount to be accessible from button2 so that I can successfully `Console.WriteLine(fagleCount);` from button2. I'm a noob and any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it showing any errors

Comment: Yes it is because button2 couldn't access faggleCount.

Answer (score 1):

instead of declaring local variable inside method body you can declare instance variable so that all members of class can access it.

```
public partial class form1 : Form
{
    int faggleCount; //declare instance variable.
    public form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Button ButtonName { get { return } }
    public static int initFaggleCount;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        faggleCount = initFaggleCount++; //use instance variable
        string finalCalc = faggleCount.ToString();
        label1.Text = finalCalc;
        /*
        Console.WriteLine(faggleCount);
        Console.ReadLine();*/
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("SavedFaggleCount.txt");
        tw.WriteLine();
        tw.Close();*/
        Console.WriteLine(faggleCount); //use instance variable
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can now access faggleCount from everywhere but it's int value doesn't transfer between the private classes. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more, like show me what that would look like with the sample code I supplied?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, *faggleCount is local to the method* i.e. only code in the method can access it. What you need to do is to move the variable to the class-level. like this:

```
public class form1 : Form {
    int faggleCount;
    //your other code here
}
```

As you can see, the variable is now in the class, not in the method. This way all the methods in the class can access it, and even a inner class can access it too!

This problem is very common among beginners. Understanding the *scope* of the variable is pretty hard. In short, **A variable in a class can be accessed in the class, a variable in a method can be accessed in the method.**

Comment: The int value doesn't transfer between the private classes. How can I do this?

Comment: The int value should not be transferred between private classes. There must be something wrong with your design. But if you really want to do so, change `int faggleCount` to `public int faggleCount`.